# I wanted to sort my duplicated characters in alphabetical order, what can I do?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Chupapi {

static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String str = "";
    System.out.print("Enter string: ");
    str = input.nextLine();

    getConsonantCount(str);
}

public static void getConsonantCount(String str) {
    char string[] = str.toCharArray();

    System.out.print("Duplicate characters in a given string: ");
    for(int i = 0, count = 0; i <string.length; i++) {
        count = 1;
        for(int j = i+1; j <string.length; j++) {
            if(string[i] == string[j] && string[i] != ' ') {
                count++;
                string[j] = '0';
            }
        }
        if(count > 1 && string[i] != '0')
            System.out.print(string[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

I wanted to sort out the "Duplicate characters in a given string: " output like in an alphabetical order example is,

```
"Duplicate characters in a given string: heuro"
 I want it to be
"Duplicate characters in a given string: ehoru"
```

That's preatty much all that I want to do with this code, any tips on what should I do or use?

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-sort-a-string-in-java-alphabetically-in-java

Comment: Use `Arrays.sort()` method: Make an array of char and add each char of your string into that array and call `Arrays.sort(<your char array>)` and rather than using Arrays.sort  try implementing bubble sort on the char array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **Arrays.sort()** to sort the array before finding duplicate characters.

```
public static void getConsonantCount(String str)
{
    char string[] = str.toCharArray();

    Arrays.sort(string);
    
    System.out.print("Duplicate characters in a given string: ");
    for (int i = 0, count = 0; i < string.length; i++)
    {
        count = 1;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < string.length; j++)
        {
            if (string[i] == string[j] && string[i] != ' ')
            {
                count++;
                string[j] = '0';
            }
        }
        if (count > 1 && string[i] != '0')
            System.out.print(string[i]);
    }
}
```